# MVC in javascript : Should i use callback when instantiating the three entities?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, callback

I'm trying to use an MVC pattern in javascript and i stumbled upon a problem.

I was using this :

```
var model = new Model();
var view = new View(model);
var controller = new Controller(view, model);
```

Refering to those three entities :

```
//MODEL(empty yet but it's normal)
function Model() {
}

//VIEW
function View(model) {
    this._model = model;
    this._drawLogin();
}

//CONTROLLER
function Controller(model, view) {
    this._model = model;
    this._view = view;
    this._displayView();
    console.log(view);
}
```

In my console.log(view) from my controller, it returns an empty object and I don't understand why.

```
Object {  }
```

Does it have to do with call back functions ? Should I instantiate each entities through a callback function to make sure one is created before the other one does ?

I tried something like this with no success :

```
function createModel(createView) {
    model = new Model();
    createView = function(createController) {
        view = new View(model)
        createController = function() {
            controller = new Controller(model,view);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I indeed had to go for a callback. Here is what I have done. :

```
var model;
var view;
var controller;

function createMVC(createModel, createView, createController) {
    createModel();
    createView();
    createController();
}
function createModel() {
    model = new Model();
}
function createView() {
    view = new View(model);
}
function createController() {
    controller = new Controller(model, view);
}
createMVC(createModel, createView, createController);
```